# Unusual C++ function declaration

Tags: c++, function, prototype, declaration

There are a few legal ways which can we declare a function in C++.

Some of the legal ways are:

```
void function ();
void function (void);
dataType function (dataType);

and so on...
```

Recently, I came across a function declaration as such:

```
void (function) ();  //Take note of the braces around the function name
```

I have never seen somehting like this before, when I tested it in a C++ compiler, it runs without any warning or compilation errors.

**My question is**: Why is `void (function) ();` a legal way to decalre a function prototype? Is there any special meaning to declare a function in this way? Or does it just work normally like any other function declaration?

Comment: Why `(5)` is a legal integer expression? Same thing here. Why not `(void function (void))` then, you ask? It's a long and sad story, that started as an interesting but completely misguided concept of "declaration syntax follows use syntax", and we are stuck with it.

Comment: I'd like to point out that `void function (void);` actually is `C` syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One difference is that enclosing it in parenthesis prevents the function-like macros expansion by the preprocessor. As mentioned in the other answers it makes no difference though to the actual compiler.

For instance:

```
// somewhere buried deep in a header
#define function(a, b) a + b

// your code
void function() {  // this expands the macro and gives compilation error
}

void (function)() { // this does not expand and works as expected
}
```

This comes in handy for instance when the bright minds behind the Microsoft Visual Studio library decided to provide function-like macros for things like `min` and `max`. (There are other ways like `#undef` to go around this).

Note that object-like macros (e.g. `#define function 3 + 4`) are still expanded.

---

The preprocessor is just a dumb text replacement tool (as opposed to the compiler which is just a (smart) text replacement tool). It takes the macro definition and replaces it everywhere. He is not aware of the semantics of what he replaces.

For instance:

```
// somewhere buried deep in a header
#define function 3 + 2

// your code
void function() {
}
```

The preprocessor sees the word `function` and textually replaces it with the string `3 + 2`. He is unaware that `function` is a id-name part of a function declaration and definition. After the preprocess phase there come the actual compile phases. So the compiler actually sees:

```
// your code
void 3 + 2() {
}
```

which does not make any sense to him and gives an error.

For function-like macros

```
// somewhere buried deep in a header
#define function(a, b) a + b
```

The preprocessor does the same except that it expects two ‘tokens’ enclosed in parenthesis separated by comma (the parameters) and does the replacement. (again no semantics aware):

```
int d = function(2, 3);
//will be replaced by the preprocessor to:
int d = 2 + 3; // passes compilation phase

void function();
// the preprocessor doesn’t find the arguments for function so it gives an error.
```

However if it encounters `(function)` it will not try to expand it (it ignores it). It is just a rule.

Comment: Do you mind explain a bit little more on the macro exppansion and why placing braces around the function name makes a difference? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

it's the same as

```
void function();
```

you can declare it as

```
void ((function)) ();
```

if you want :)

be careful not to mix this up with the function pointer declaration syntax.

Comment: So I supposed this is like `int x = (3);` where the bracket is redundant and will be left out? thanks for your reply.

Comment: essentially yeah. Although like bolov said, there's this little difference with macros which I overlooked when I answered :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find that was:

```
void (*function) ();
```

since there is no benefit to using `void (function)();` or `void (((((function)))))();` for that matter, they're equivalent. If I'm mistaken and it's not a typo, the answer is that you can put as many parentheses around the function name as you like, subject to compiler limitations, as per the code for `output6()` below.

If I'm *not* mistaken, that one with the `*` actually declares a function *pointer* which can be used to hold a pointer to a function. It does not declare a function at all, just a pointer that can be used to *reference* a function.

Like an `int` pointer (for example), the function pointer can point to an arbitrary function, parameters notwhithstanding.

So for example:

```
#include <iostream>

void (((((output6)))))() { std::cout << 6; }
void output7() { std::cout << 7; }
void output8() { std::cout << 8; }
void (*fn)();

int main() {
    fn = &output6; fn();
    fn = &output7; fn();
    fn = &output8; fn();
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

would output `678`.

Comment: So can I say that `void function()` is the same as `void (function)()` in my case ?

Comment: Why the downvote? There's nothing in this answer that's wrong and I'm pretty certain OP just mistyped since there's _NO_ reason why any proficient coder would use `void (function)();`.

Comment: I believe the down-vote was because you presumed he mistyped (although I think in the OP case it was just (function)() - this being said, your answer is well written and informative and gives all the key information. shall +1 you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about it, it means exactly the same as the version without parentheses. It is just an artifact of how the syntax is declared. Usually you see the use of parentheses around the function name when a function pointer is declared, e.g.

```
void (*function_pointer)() = nullptr;
// a function pointer to a function taking and returning void
```

in contrast to

```
void *function();
// a function declaration of a function taking void and returning void*
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it works the same as a normal function because function pointers are declared like: `void (*function)()` so if you leave out the `*` then it should be just a function.

Answer (score 0):

It corresponds to the C++ grammar. If to simplify then one of the rules for defining of the declarator looks as

```
declarator:

   (declarator)
```

So you can write for example

```
void (function) ();
```

or

```
void ( (function) () );
```

or even the following way

```
struct A
{
   void ( ( function )() const );
};
```